# Understanding semantic driven and symbolic execution based test case generation

Tags: automated-testing, test-design, testcase

I'm trying to understand aspects of automatic test case generation (tcg) from models. During my research, I came across two "techniques" called **sematic driven tcg** and **symbolic execution based tcg**. About the latter, I found some information sporadically that helped me to understand this approach a bit.

But I don't know how to understand semantic driven in the context of automatic test case generation. I can imagine that semantic information are connected to the model from which the tc are generated. But how? And which (semantic) information?

Is there any connection between these two approaches?